# enum + IsDefined

Tags: c#, .net

Given this:

```
public enum SomeTypes
{
    SomeType1 = 1,
    SomeType2 = 2,
    SomeType3 = 3
}
```

and a class:

```
public SomeClass
{
public SomeTypes SomeType { get; set; };
}
```

What is the best way to check if the enum is within range (i.e. not 0). I guess it would involve IsDefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum SomeTypes {
    SomeType1 = 1,
    SomeType2 = 2,
    SomeType3 = 3
}
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeTypes SomeType { get; set; }

    bool validEnum() {
        return System.Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SomeTypes), this.SomeType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in the `set` accessor:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private SomeTypes _SomeType;
    public SomeTypes SomeType { 
        get {return _SomeType;} 
        set {
            if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SomeTypes),value)) 
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a valid SomeTypes value", value),"value");
            _SomeType = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I would rather check it when I explicitly validate the object.

Comment: Also, this would only check the value when setting it. Unless the field is initialized to a valid value, it would remain invalid until set.